# OpenLayers 3 load geometry from SQL

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

I am trying to load a MultiPolygon to a Geo Jason Object from SQL and it's not working..

What DOES Work (this creates the geometry object)...

```
var geoJsonObj = {
    'type': 'Feature',
    'geometry': {
        "coordinates": [
            [[[-91.0759333619999, 40.15440933399983],
                [-91.066378752, 40.154309680999823],
                [-91.066282352, 40.157927062999832],
                [-91.0751007809999, 40.157994385999814],
                [-91.0758658189999, 40.157997289999805],
                [-91.075866624, 40.157608482999827],
                [-91.0758737049999, 40.157300970999813],
                [-91.0759333619999, 40.15440933399983]]]
        ]
        , "type": "MultiPolygon"
    }

};
```

What Does NOT work...

```
var geoJsonObj = {
    'type': 'Feature',
    'geometry': webMapValues.geometry
};
```

where webMapValues.geometry is populated from SQL and has a value of...

```
"{
"coordinates":
[[[
[-91.0759333619999,40.15440933399983],
[-91.066378752,40.154309680999823],
[-91.066282352,40.157927062999832],
[-91.0751007809999,40.157994385999814],
[-91.0758658189999,40.157997289999805],
[-91.075866624,40.157608482999827],
[-91.0758737049999,40.157300970999813],
[-91.0759333619999,40.15440933399983]
]]]
,"type":"MultiPolygon"}"
```

notice the only difference is that the value in the variable loaded by SQL is inside "" quotes.

I've tried a couple "format" solutions but seem to be running into a dead end.

Any Help is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual answer was to use JSON.parse like this...

```
JSON.parse(response.FieldList[key].Shape)
```

as the structure coming back from SQL was already a proper GeoJson object to Toby Speight's point and OL3 takes a string I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the JSON string into an object which you then can merge with geoJSON object frame and add to OpenLayers.

```js
var geomStr = '{"coordinates":[[[[-91.0759333619999, 40.15440933399983],[-91.066378752, 40.154309680999823],[-91.066282352, 40.157927062999832],[-91.0751007809999, 40.157994385999814],[-91.0758658189999, 40.157997289999805],[-91.075866624, 40.157608482999827],[-91.0758737049999, 40.157300970999813],[-91.0759333619999, 40.15440933399983]]]],"type":"MultiPolygon"}';

var geoJson = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": JSON.parse(geomStr)
    }]
};

var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        features: new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(geoJson, {
            dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
            featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
        })
    })
});

var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    controls: [],
    layers: [new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
    }), vectorLayer],
    view: new ol.View({
        center: [0, 0],
        zoom: 10
    })
});

map.getView().fit(
    vectorLayer.getSource().getExtent(),
    map.getSize());
```

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#map {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ol3/3.16.0/ol.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ol3/3.16.0/ol.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: dang... just see that you got there while i was playing with the code snippet.